# JavaScript: add an Eventlistener, that executes a function using the elements Parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a list of html elements, that have an attibute `taskNr`.

What I'm trying to achieve: when one of those elements is clicked, another element should be deleted. The `id` of the element to delete is "task" and the taskNr from the clicked element.

I have tried this:

```
var tasknumbers = [];

// fügt eventlistener für button removetask hinzu
function activateremovetasklistener(){
    var removeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-times-circle floatright fa-fw notfirst");
    for (i = 0; i < removeBtns.length; i++) {
       tasknumbers[i] = removeBtns[i].getAttribute("taskNr");
       removeBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {removeTask(i);});
    };

}

//entfernt Task bei Klick auf X
function removeTask(index){
    var taskNr = tasknumbers[index];
    var taskClass = document.getElementById("task" + taskNr);
    taskClass.remove();
}
```

Instead of the taskNr of the element having the Eventlistener it uses the tasknr from the Array.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Auf StackOverflow werden grundsätzlich nur **englische** Fragen beantwortet :)

Comment: @MarvinJWendt ok

Comment: please provide the relevant html (see [mcve]) and also clarify what actually happens instead of the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the Funktion gets the wrong Parameter. this Can be solved by giving it the Event, causing the Eventlistener to be activated, as parameter. So you can get the right taskNr inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are overwriting tasknumber. Remove tasknumber from the click function, I guess this should work!

```
for (i= 0; i< removeBtns.length; i++) {
    var tasknumber = removeBtns[i].getAttribute("taskNr");
    removeBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var taskClass = document.getElementById("task" + tasknumber);
            taskClass.remove();

    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you I have tried your changes, but it only works the first time, after that it is not able to find the taskClass.